# symmetry of a function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, convex-analysis

Let $\nabla{}H$ be the gradient of $H:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$,
$$
\nabla{}H(x)=\left(\frac{\partial{}H}{\partial{}x_{i}}(x)\right)_{i=1,\ldots,n}^{\intercal}
$$

A proper scoring function, defined on an open, convex set $B$, $S:B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$ is the positive orthant, is a function which fulfills the following constraint:
$$
\langle x,S(x)\rangle>\langle y,S(x)\rangle\mbox{ for all }x\neq{}y\in{}B
$$
where $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}$. Convex analysis shows that for each proper scoring function, there is a convex entropy function $H:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a divergence function $d:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$ such that (if $H$ is differentiable, which I will assume for now)
$$
\nabla{}H(x)=S(x)
$$
$$
H(x)=\langle x,S(x)\rangle\mbox{ and}
$$
$$
d(x,y)=H(x)-H(y)-\langle x-y,\nabla{}H(y)\rangle
$$
I want to show that only the Brier score $S(x)=\left(2x_{i}-1-\sum_{j}x_{j}^{2}\right)_{i=1,\ldots,n}^{\intercal}$ (and irrelevantly linear transformations of it, $\hat{S}(x)=kS(x)+b,k\in\mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$) is symmetric in the sense that
$$
d(x,y)=d(y,x)\mbox{ for all }x,y\in{}B
$$
There are proofs for this in the literature, but I want to show it using the Legendre-Fenchel duality. The dual of the function $H$ is $H^{\ast}$, which is defined on $\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|\nabla{}H(x)=y,x\in{}B\}$. Here is what I know about it that may be relevant for the proof.
$$
\left(\nabla{}H\right)^{-1}=\nabla{}H^{\ast}
$$
$$
H^{\ast\ast}=H
$$
$$
d(x,y)=d^{\ast}(y^{\ast},x^{\ast}),\mbox{ where }x^{\ast}=\nabla{}H(x)
$$
Most importantly, the only self-dual function is
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle x,x\rangle\Leftrightarrow{}F=F^{\ast}
$$
This should be enough information to prove that only the Brier score is symmetric, but I can't pull it off without help.

Comment: B cannot be an open ball around zero? Am I right?

Comment: I don't remember seeing a restriction like that in the convex analysis book that I was using. However, in my application, the zero-vector is indeed for good reasons not part of the domain of $F$.

Comment: This condition  $$\langle x,S(x)\rangle>\langle y,S(x)\rangle\mbox{ for all }x,y\in{}B$$

implies $0 \notin B$

Comment: In my application, $B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$ is the positive orthant. I have edited the question to reflect this fact. Thanks, Red Shoes.

Comment: I also just edited an earlier mischaracterization of the Brier score on my part. The correct version is above, the incorrect version had $\sum_{i}x_{i}\left(2x_{i}-1-\sum_{j}x^{2}_{j}\right)$.